# zooKeeper external vs internal?

Tags: hbase, apache-zookeeper

I couldn't understand well while configuring zooKeeper managing HBASE internally and externally, what are the differences, the advantage and disadvantage?

Answer (score 1):

when you have 100+ datanode ,how can you managing hbase internally ?
In Apache HBase, ZooKeeper coordinates, communicates, and shares state between the Masters and RegionServers. HBase has a design policy of using ZooKeeper only for transient data (that is, for coordination and state communication). Thus if the HBase’s ZooKeeper data is removed, only the transient operations are affected – data can continue to be written and read to/from HBase.
you can get more from [here](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/10/what-are-hbase-znodes/)

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not you want HBase to manage zookeeper depends on what you are going to run on your cluster.  If HBase is the only system that users zookeeper, you can use HBase scripts to manage zookeeper.  If you have several other systems that use zookeeper as well, such as Solr, you might want to consider managing zookeeper separately, or as part of a unified distribution (Cloudera, MapR, Hortonworks).

One advantage of using HBase to manage zookeeper is that the configuration is the same as configuring HBase, in the same configuration file, using XML format.  Default standalone zookeeper configuration users a different format, and the configuration files are stored in a different location.

One disadvantage of using HBase to manage zookeeper is that the default scripts will start and stop zookeeper when you start-all / stop-all in HBase.  You can mitigate this by modifying the start/stop scripts to separate the zookeeper portion from the master/regionserver portions.